(scipy) setting prominence in signal.find_peaks
BACKGROUND
I am processing a radio signals on a Rpi5 with a Software Defined Radio (SDR) in python and need to adaptively set the prominence parameter of scipy signal.find_peaks.
METHOD
The SDR is sampling at 768k samples/sec and I am processing in 256k chunk sizes.
The 256k chunks enter the processing que, a PSD using signal.find_peaks determines where peaks (and hence frequencies) in the chunk are potential signals for processing. The chunk of samples is then channelized into 1024 channels and only those frequencies with power are further processed.
Note: the further processing can determine which frequencies have valid signals vs noise
p = signal.find_peaks(spec, prominence=0.000010)[0]

EXAMPLES
A example plot with prominence 0.00001 and a single signal of interest correctly identified at 160.377 is shown below. Note the other peaks are noise or DC spikes.

If a different set of samples from the SDR is then processed with signal.find_peaks with the same prominence setting of 0.00001 I get so many peaks the Rpi5 can no longer process in real time and samples are dropped:
(Note signal of interest still on 160.377)

POSSIBLE SOLUTION
I have considered that I could leave the prominence set very low so I get a lot of peaks and only process the 20 strongest which is approximately the maximum number of signals I can process at once on a Rpi5.
QUESTION
Question: Is there a way to adaptively set the prominence?
Note: Please let me know if further information is require and I will update the question. Links to sample data can be provided.
